# Google Tag Manager is invalid or missing

Tags: google-tag-manager

We are trying to install Enhanced commerce plugin with GTM, all seems correctly working, for example all data layer seems to work fine (see below) 
but we still have an error "Google Tag Manager is invalid or missing, check screenshot taken: 
[image]

Comment: Can you post your GTM snippet in relation to your page? Also, don't see your dataLayer as you mentioned.

Comment: I am getting the exact same screen. The weird part is that that I created a tag for Universal Analytics and, like you, the tag is working. I can view new data in Google Analytics dashboard. Thus, the account ID is obviously correct. This seems to be a false error but would like to confirm. Cannot find anything on this yet.

Answer (score 0):

Google Tag Assistant gives currently false positive messages on newly created GTM accounts. Those account have wider IDs: GTM-ABCDEFG (7 chars after GTM- prefix) which is not recognized correctly by Google Tag Assistant.

You can continue working with the plugin and your GTM account, it will work fine.

**https://wordpress.org/support/topic/invalid-or-missing-account-id
by: duracelltomi**

Answer (score 0):

It is also mentioned now in the official TagAssistant Documentation that this is an issue for the longer IDs and will be resolved in a future update:
https://support.google.com/tagassistant/answer/3207128?hl=en#invalid_id